# C++ Heap Corruption Detected While Deleting Array

Tags: c++, debugging, heap-memory, corruption, stack-memory

I've been getting a Heap Corruption error in the pop() function of a DynamicStack i've been trying to make.

Right now i've set it so that if the number of items is less than around 1/4 of the capacity I set earlier, then the DynamicStack will half itself in size (unless the new halved capacity is less than my original capacity).

The exact error I get (using Visual C++) is:

HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED: After Normal block ($154) at 0x010AF0D0.
CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer

```
StackItem DynamicStack::pop()
{
    if (size_ == 0)
        return EMPTY_STACK;
    StackItem thingToReturn = items_[size_ - 1]; // The item to return is at location size - 1
    size_--;
    if ((size_ <= capacity_ * (1.0 / 4))  && capacity_ / 2 >= init_capacity_)
    {
        StackItem * items_half = new StackItem[capacity_ / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < size_; i++)
            items_half[i] = items_[i];
        capacity_ = capacity_ / 2;
        delete[] items_;    // ERROR IS HERE
        items_ = items_half;
    }
    return thingToReturn;
}
```

Here's also the push function I made for this stack

```
void DynamicStack::push(StackItem value)
{
    if (size_ != capacity_)
        items_[size_] = value;
    else
    {
        StackItem * items_new = new StackItem[capacity_ * 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < capacity_; i++)
            items_new[i] = items_[i];
        items_new[capacity_] = value;
        capacity_ = capacity_ * 2;
        delete[] items_;
        items_ = items_new;
    }
    size_++;
}
```

Here's the Default Constructor of the Dynamic Stack 
Where items_, capacity_, size_, and init_capacity_ are of type int.

```
DynamicStack::DynamicStack()
{
    items_ = new StackItem[16];
    capacity_ = 16;
    size_ = 0;
    init_capacity_ = 16;
}
```

This is the test that i'm running that's causing the heap buffer error:

```
bool test3()
    {
        DynamicStack stack(24);
        stack.push(10);
        stack.push(20);
        ASSERT_TRUE(stack.peek() == 20)
            ASSERT_TRUE(stack.pop() == 20)
            ASSERT_TRUE(stack.pop() == 10)
            ASSERT_TRUE(stack.pop() == DynamicStack::EMPTY_STACK)
            ASSERT_TRUE(stack.peek() == DynamicStack::EMPTY_STACK)
            return true;
    }
```

In main I run the test with default initialization.

```
int main()
{
    DynamicStackTest stack_test;
    bool stack_test3_passed = stack_test.test3();
    cout << "---Dynamic Stack Tests---" << endl;
    cout << "Test3: " << get_status_str(stack_test3_passed) << endl;
}
```

I expected that there shouldn't be any errors when compiling as delete[] shouldn't really need any memory allocation right? If something exists there should be no problem in deleting it.

Comment: What is the type of capacity_ .  Also of size_ and init_capacity_ ?

Comment: You should provide more information on the code, esp, the code of initialization of your stack.

Comment: ***I expected that there shouldn't be any errors when compiling as delete[] shouldn't really need any memory allocation right?*** You could have corrupted the heap at any time before this delete. Your compiler is running a special debug heap that on allocations and deallocations it trys to determine if the heap is corrupt.

Comment: The most likely problem is you are accessing your dynamic array out of bounds. Perhaps you are accessing `items_ [capacity]` somewhere in your code which is an off by one error.

Comment: You're not using the default constructor in the failing test case, so it's hardly relevant.

Comment: Through testing I noticed that the error actually might be coming from the push function, and it only occurs when I initialize my dynamic stack not using the default constructor. When I do, for example DynamicStack stack (16)

Answer (score 0):

So the answer to this is actually quite embarassing. I labelled capacity_ as capacity in DynamicStack.cpp, and basically this messed up the constructors.